# Error: Thread 1: Exception: "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Label."

Tags: swift, xcode

Thats the last part in my Code:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    if let data = characteristic.value {
        let weight: Int = data.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
        Label1.text = String(weight) + "Hz"
    }
}
```

I just want to change the Label in the String with "HZ"

Comment: You probably haven't connected the @IBOutlet in the storyboard/XIB correctly.

Comment: How can I do that

Comment: 1) Press ⇧⌘F, 2) Type `Label` and press return, 3) Click on the appropriate Interface Builder search result 4) Remove the dead connection

Comment: What you mean remove the dead connection

Comment: Im not sure but i just have to add an Label in Main storyboard and then add it in the Viewcontroller or?

Comment: There is a dead (the corresponding outlet is missing) connection `Label` in the class in Interface Builder. Remove it and connect it to `Label1`

Comment: you mean this one:@IBOutlet weak var Label1: UILabel!    ?

Comment: I mean in **Interface Builder**. Did you read my first comment and follow the steps? Please read also the duplicate.

Comment: ahh ok i know what you mean but how can i remove it and connect it to label1